# Why can Swift use { get } to declare properties in classes, shouldn't it be used in protocols?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-protocols

[image 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oe3cD.png)
I'm curious,how it can ..., and why?

[image 1.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oLoE.png)

if i use `{ get }` to declare properties in a class, it will report an error.

Comment: As they used to say back in the day, RTFM: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html#ID269 and https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html

Comment: Hello, you instead of using links to screenshots it's better to copy/paste code snippet. Or you could add your screenshots directly in the question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing `Foundation.ProcessInfo` implementation only a generated interface.
That is why you have things like :

```swift
open var hostName: String { get }
```

The implementation is elsewhere and you don't have any details about it, you only have informations you need to use `ProcessInfo` in your code. For instance you have no internal or private members declared in the generated interface.

XXProcessInfo on the other hand is a class that you are creating and you need to provide the implementation for you properties.